# Can the new ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET MVC 6) project type target regular .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core

The new ASP.NET 5 (vNext) does some great stuff like integrate Bower, Grunt, and other client side web development tools [into the project](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015).

However, it is dawning on me (after many such projects were made and scratched) that it would seem all of this is limited to projects that can target the new 'cloud' or 'cross-platform' (KRE-CLR) stack ONLY, as opposed to the regular .NET stack. As nice as it would be to target this new stack, this **severely** limits what one can target at this time (basically any dll / project you reference now isn't an ASP.NET 5 class library, so it can't be referenced, so you can't rely on this?).

Am I missing something? Can the new ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET MVC 6) project type target regular .NET?

If the answer is NO, even if this isn't possible now, do the team plan to at least add some of these client-side capabilities (bower, grunt, etc) to 'regular' ASP.NET (MVC 5) projects in the future?

Comment: What is it that you're concerned about? ASP.NET is still going to have the full capabilities of the .NET framework. It's simply that the .NET framework is going to be packaged a little differently from here on out. What does "regular .NET" have that the new setup doesn't?

Comment: I'm concerned that these client side frameworks (grunt, gulp, bower) should be added to work just as well in code that targets the full .NET framework. Besides, why wouldn't they? And in fact maybe it is possible, thus my question.

Comment: "What does 'regular .NET' have that the new setup doesn't?"
It has the ability to reference regularly compiled class libraries (dlls). I was rudely awakened to the fact that I can't reference ANY dll or project that isn't itself already an "ASP.NET 5 Class Library." For instance, I have a large code base targeting EF, but EF vnext is super alpha version right now, and there is much labor ahead to convert all of my own code based on it (including other EF based libraries, like EF.Extended, EF.MappingApi, EF.BulkInsert, etc).

Comment: From the looks of it, you can use an ordinary DLL assembly in vNext if you put it in a NuGet package: http://forums.asp.net/t/2002302.aspx?Adding+a+non+nuget+reference+to+a+vNext+project Does that help?

Comment: Thanks JLRishe! That actually taught me a lot. Unfortunately though, I did this, got a simple but regularly .NET compiled assembly packaged into a local nuget feed location. All of that worked great, and it imported great. However, once imported, that dll in references showed a yellow caution symbol, and the web site would compile but throw errors on startup. It clearly doesn't work, and in fact I don't know how it could, as the source framework is not the full .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [a new post by Scott Guthrie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Z0h.png), he seems to confirm that ASP.NET 5 absolutely should work with the full .NET framework, in fact, even saying:

> "Your existing applications and libraries will work **without modification** on this [full .NET] runtime."

Here's the full citation:

> ASP.NET 5 works with two runtime environments to give you greater flexibility when hosting your app. The two runtime choices are: ([a] ***.NET Core*** ... [b] ***.NET Framework –*** The API for .NET Core is currently more limited than the full .NET Framework, so you may need to modify existing apps to target .NET Core. If you don't want to have to update your app you can instead run ASP.NET 5 applications on the full .NET Framework (version 4.5.2 and above).  When doing this you have access to the complete set of .NET Framework APIs. Your existing applications and libraries will work without modification on this runtime.

While I am very glad to hear this, the problems discussed in this question and by other posters here makes it seem like this target goal does not yet match the current reality. In simplest terms, we need not only to be able to target the full .NET, but to simply reference current .NET dll/assemblies. Currently, it seems the only assemblies that work are ones built against .NET Core.

The answer to this dilemma then? I believe the answer is: *It's coming*. This according to [the new Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/23/aspnet-5-updates-for-feb-2015.aspx):

> **System References are back**
>
> You can now ***easily add references to system assemblies using the Add References dialog***, which will make the appropriate modifications to your project.json file... *We are also hard at work to enable support **for adding references to user assemblies*** for a future preview release.

[image]

(picture from that article)

So then, this is GREAT news! This also justifies that, according to these posts, these indeed have been shortcomings up till now (and still exist for user assemblies for the moment).

Comment: He we are in November 2015 and we still don't have the ability to add our own class library projects to an MVC 6 project.  Or rather, you can try but will most likely get reference error.

Comment: Yeah, it's disappointing. It is going RC here this month though at least, and the conference this Wednesday may have some goodies for us. Maybe this will be resolved in the next month or so.

Comment: Has this been resolved? I need to reference a dll that calls an old web service (not svc, but older) haven't been able to find anything on it yet for RC1. Thought I would use RC1 rather than the old Web API so I don't have to redo the project in a few months...not sure if that is going to be possible.

Comment: @Jon49 please let us know what you find out. I am eager to know what is and isn't working by now, but I am not involved in the new project type at this moment.

Comment: I asked a new question. I guess it works just fine if you don't reference dnxCore50. See the first comment under the question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34661624/632495

Answer (score 4):

As per my experience with the latest version of Visual Studio CTP 5, here are few things to consider:

1. In CTP 5 it now allows you to add a reference to a regular class library.
2. In ASP.net vNext they target a different framework to support cross platform, and this is newly supported
   For example, if you only choose aspnet50 in frameworks (project.json) and runtime is CLR then it will use full .NET Framework, so you can use almost all functionality like in ASP.NET MVC 5.
   If you want to work with aspnetcore50 then it is possible that much functionality will not be available, or even many be under development.
3. If you have built your own class library and you want to add a reference to it, then in VS 2015 preview and CTP5 you have to publish NUGET package and then use that package to reference that DLL.
4. If you want to use a regular .NET assembly (for example System.DirectoryService) then make sure that you have only one framework in project.json.

**Update**

I assume that you are using Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5.

Here is copy of my project.json

```
{
    /* Click to learn more about project.json  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=517074 */
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta2",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2",
        /* "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta2", */
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta2",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta1"
    },
    "commands": {
        /* Change the port number when you are self hosting this application */
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
        "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
        "ef":  "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },
    **"frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
            "MyCoolLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
            } }

    },**
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "packExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "postrestore": [ "npm install" ],
        "prepare": [ "grunt bower:install" ]
    }
}
```

My custom class library in MyCoolLibrary and it is added in framework dependencies not dependencies. Also I build my library using .NET Framework 4.5. ( Not 4.5.3) so it support older version as well.

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 Preview then also above thing will work.

Comment: These are very helpful remarks! Point #2 helps a lot in recognizing it's possible to simply delete aspnetcore50. However, when I right click project -Properties, it displays a dropbox with title: "Target KRE version." And the two options are both KRE (KRE-CLR-x86 and KRE-CLR-amd64). So how can I specify I want to target not this 'KRE' cloud version but the regular CLR? (Or maybe KRE is something else?) SO: After deleting aspnetcore50, I still can't reference a regular dll, and referencing that dll as a nuget package I made, it works but then shows yellow sign (obviously an error) still.

Comment: Which dll you have tried to add and share that image in question?

Comment: The dll is a very simple project / assembly whose only dependencies beyond basic C# stuff is System.Xml and System.Linq.Xml. The point being, this is a very basic assembly that is a good test case, if IT doesn't work, none should. I made this into a local nuget package and am referencing it in a local nuget feed (after making your changes I still can't add a simple ref), which all works, it installs in nuget and all, but then in references the added assembly has a little yellow caution sign over it (as well as the same yellow sign on the root ASP.NET 5.0 references node).

Comment: So is there something else I need to do to allow regular .NET stuff to work? The project properties hardly has any options available, but I can't seen anything that would work. And looking through project.json I don't see another option to play with with regard to changing the framework...

Comment: Yellow sign is that it is not find something in reference. That is why I ask that if you share your project.json and snap of yellow sign with expanded then I can help as I have tested to added existing .NET assembly and you have to add those in depencies section in project.json under framework.

Comment: Thanks. I just made a bran new vNext project (again), have changed virtually nothing except having deleted the aspnetcore50 reference in proj.json. While my nuget package shows up and installs just fine from nuget, and while this does add the name and version of that package within dependencies, it still shows the same yellow caution sign, and I notice that in proj.json intellisense doesn't work when I type it's name. Also, I just added a bogus name to dependices in proj.json and it shows the same yellow sign. So maybe proj.json isn't reconizing my nuget source?

Answer (score 1):

Client side capabilities aren't connected to dll's.  They can be added to older ASP .NET projects from Nuget packages.

Comment: "do the team plan to at least add some of these client-side capabilities (bower, grunt, etc) to 'regular' ASP.NET (MVC 5) projects in the future?"  - regular asp .net projects can add those client side capabilities via nuget packages.  Default project templates aren't available.

Comment: Thank you Clive. While I think your first sentence misread what I stated ("Client side [framework] capabilities aren't connected to dll's." - I never said this), you are mentioning something very pertinent indeed. When I search in nuget for 'bower' or 'grunt' (even in VS 2014) I do indeed see nuget packages for these! However, are these the exact same things as what's available in the new ASP.NET (in VStudio 2015)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem but you can target the regular CLR in new projects.

In your project.json file comment out both aspnet50 and aspnetcore50 and use net45 instead:

```
{    
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "net45": { 
            "dependencies": { }
        }
        /* 
        "aspnet50" : { },
        "aspnetcore50": { } */
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! However I just did what you said and suddenly no ASP.NET types are recognized at all (IActionResult, Controller, HttpPost, nothing). But it DID change so under References the root node is now called .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: How can you change in these projects the target framework? I.e. 4.5.3 opposite 4.6, etc? Maybe that's one contributing problem? (I'm not referring to other referenced projects

Comment: To be clear, none of these are recognized now: using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc; No Microsoft.AspNet at all (i.e. the AspNet namespace part is not even available in the intellisense, and red squiggly "The type or namespace 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) And yet all I did was change 'aspnet50' to 'net45' as you said.

Comment: @NicholasPetersen They're not recognised because they don't target net45 themselves. I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is possible at this stage. In the standard CLR, you would reference System.Web.Mvc to get all the MVC stuff. In the above config file you would but that reference under net45 dependencies, but that doesn't work.