# Add dll to MVC6 or use old web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to reference a `dll` which calls an old web service (not svc, but the older one). I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. I'm using the `RC1` version. I could call the web service directly but I'm not sure how to do that either in MVC6.

If I add the `dll` directly I get the error:

```
The name '*' does not exist in the current context
FieldOps.DNX Core 5.0
```

Here's what part of my `project.json` looks like where the library added is called "MyLibrary":

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": { "MyLibrary": "2.2.0" }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
        "System.ServiceModel.Primitives": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
        "System.ServiceModel.Http": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.ServiceModel.NetTcp": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
        "System.ServiceModel.Duplex": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Net.NameResolution": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Net.Security": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Security.Principal.Windows": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Diagnostics.Tools": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Remove the whole `dnxcore50` section so that your library only targets `dnx451` if you want to reference an assembly that is not core50 compatible.